# accessing files outside baseUrl with Yii

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm using the Yii framework. This is my directory structure:

```
folder
    images
    yii-framework
    mysite
       index.php
       protected
       assets
       .
       '
   '
```

"`folder`" is the `webroot`.My subdomain `a.subdomain.com` points to `mysite`. The problem is I want to use the images from the "image" folder in "mysite".

The following code works well for localhost but not on the webserver:

```
echo "<img src='".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/../images/image1.png' height='500' width='500'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually Yii makes this relatively simple provided you have the right setup. If you have the websites webroots running on the same file system, you can pre publish them with their true file system paths and Yii will pass you a publicly available URL to serve them with having copied them to the sites assets folder.

```
$url = Yii::app()->assetManager->publish('/path/to/webroot/images/imageIWant.jpg')
echo "<img src='".Yii::app()->assetManager->baseUrl.'/'.$url."' height='500' width='500'>";
```

That should do it for you, make sure to prepend the assetManager's baseURL too just in case it changes.

EDIT:
If you do decide this route, this is worth a read, actually the entire wiki is worth a read :p

[Understanding "Assets"](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets)

Answer (score 2):

You can only use:

```
<img src="/images/image1.png"/>
```

This should work. No need to give the absolute URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is by definition not possible, neither with Yii nor without. There is no command that can make a browser get an image outside the web root.

You would have to build a script that loads the image for you, and passes it through. That is a very inefficient way to serve an image, though. It's probably much better to move the images into the web root.

Comment: But there must be some way. I've multiple subdomains. If I move the "images" to under one root folder then again the same problem reappears for other subdomains

Comment: And yes one more thing "folder" is the web root. But the subdomain points to "mysite"